# Bash quotes unescaped on command substitution

Tags: linux, bash, unix, script, shell-script

Can someone explain me why this is working (listing the contents of a directory that has a whitespace in its name):

```
ret="$(ls "my dir")"
```

Shouldn't it rather be interpreted as:

```
ret="$(ls "
my dir
")"
```

As for example with:

```
ls "my" "dir"
```

and

```
ls "my dir"
```

Comment: I am asking why ret="$(ls "my dir")" is working.

Comment: I can only guess that bash is "smart" enough to see that a `"$("` would be a syntax error (`$` inside `"` is evaluated) and tries to find another match which allows the nesting of `"` in this case.

Comment: Related: [How are double quotation marks in `bash` matched (paired)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421729/how-are-double-quotation-marks-in-bash-matched-paired)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best guess so far seems to be that you are asking:

> The command
>
> ```
>     ret="$(ls "my dir")"
> ```
>
> is a pretty terrible example of a command
>   that contains four double-quote (`"`) marks. 
>   One might naïvely expect that the second quote would match the first one,
>   and the fourth would match the third, like this:
>
> ```
>     ret="$(ls "my dir")"
>         ↑-----↑      ↑-↑
> ```
>
> as, for example, happens with
>
> ```
>     eat "afternoon snack" dinner "midnight snack"
> ```
>
> Instead, it “works”, as follows:
>
> ```
>     ret="$(ls "my dir")"
>         ↑     ↑------↑ ↑
>         ↑--------------↑
> ```
>
> Why are the nested quotes parsed that way?

This paragraph of [bash(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash)
may explain it:

> #### Command Substitution
>
>   ⋮
>   …  When using the
>   `$(command)`
>   form,
>     all characters between the parentheses make up the command ….

I guess this means what you have observed, namely,
the text between the `$(` and the `)` is treated
as if it were a separate command, with its own parsing/pairing of quotes,
independent of syntactic elements outside the parentheses. 
I concede that, if you aren’t looking for that meaning,
it’s very hard to interpret.

---

But your question, as written, doesn’t make sense. 
The whole thing hinges on the very special meaning(s) of `$` to the shell. 
If we changed that to some other currency symbol,

```
    ret="£(ls "my dir")"
```

then it would be treated as two words:

`ret="£(ls "my`
<sub>(followed by)</sub>
                                    `dir")"`

because, if a non-blank, non-special character appears
immediately before an opening quote or immediately after a closing quote,
it is included in the same string as the characters enclosed in the quotes. 
For example,

```
    cat Wal"*"mart
```

looks for a file called `Wal*mart`,
not a file called `Wal`, one called `*`, and one called `mart` —
`Wal"*"mart` is equivalent to `Wal\*mart` and `"Wal*mart"`. 
Similarly, the following example shows four words:

```
    one" "two  buckle" my "shoe  /don\'t/be/a/" "/cadet  sqrt"(2)"
    ↑-------↑  ↑--------------↑  ↑--------------------↑  ↑-------↑
```

I don’t know where you got the three-line breakdown
that you showed in your question.

Comment: It's how i would expect it to behave.