# Difference between ${} and $() in a shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, centos, script

```
$ echo $(date)
Thu Jul 2 16:33:11 SGT 2015
$ echo ${date}

$ name=foo
$ echo $(name)
ksh: name:  not found

$ echo ${name}
foo
```

Seems like `${variable}` is the same as `$variable`, while `$()` is to execute a command. Why use `${}` then?

Comment: Related:  [`${ ` *`variable_name `* `}` doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525 "titled “Single or double brackets”")

Answer (score 76):

`$(command)` is “command substitution”. 
As you seem to understand, it runs the *`command`*, captures its output,
and inserts that into the command line that contains the **`$(…)`**; e.g.,

```
$ ls -ld $(date +%B).txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Noob Noob    867 Jul  2 11:09 July.txt
```

`${parameter}` is “parameter substitution”. 
A lot of information can be found in the shell’s man page, [bash(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash),
under the “**Parameter Expansion**” heading:

> `${parameter}`
>
>   The value of
>   *parameter*
>   is substituted. 
>   The braces are required when
>   *parameter*
>   is a positional parameter
>   with more than one digit, or when
>   *parameter*
>   is followed by a character
>   which is not to be interpreted as part of its name.

For positional parameters, see “**Positional Parameters**”, below. 
In its most common usage, as shown in the other answers,
*`parameter`* is a variable name. 
The `${…}` form, as stated at the end of the paragraph above,
lets you get the value of a variable
(i.e., `$variable_name`)
and follow it immediately with a letter, digit, or underscore:

```
$ animal=cat
$ echo $animals
                                # No such variable as “animals”.
$ echo ${animal}s
cats
$ echo $animal_food
                                # No such variable as “animal_food”.
$ echo ${animal}_food
cat_food
```

You can also do this with quotes:

```
$ echo "$animal"s
cats
```

Or, as an exercise in options, you could use a second variable:

```
$ plural=s
$ echo $animal$plural
cats
```

But this is just step 1. 
The next paragraph in the man page is interesting, although a little cryptic:

> If the first character of *parameter*
> is an exclamation point (**`!`**),
> a level of variable indirection is introduced. 
> Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of *parameter*
> as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded
> and that value is used in the rest of the  substitution,
> rather than the value of *parameter* itself. 
> This is known as *indirect expansion*.    
> <sub>…*(exceptions)*…</sub>  
> The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace
> in order to introduce indirection.

I’m not sure how I can make this clearer except by example:

```
$ animal=cat
$ echo $animal
cat
$ cat=tabby
$ echo $cat
tabby
$ echo ${!animal}
tabby                           # If $animal is “cat”, then ${!animal} is $cat, i.e., “tabby”
```

So let’s call that step 1½. 
There are lots of interesting things that you can do as step 2:

```
$ animal=cat
$ echo ${#animal}
3                               # String length
$ echo ${animal/at/ow}
cow                             # Substitution
```

You can’t do any of those things without the `{`…`}` braces.

**Positional Parameters**

Consider this *artificial* example:

```
$ cat myecho.sh
echo $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 $10 $11 $12 $13 $14 $15
$ ./myecho.sh Hey diddle diddle, The cat and the fiddle, The cow jumped over the moon.
Hey diddle diddle, The cat and the fiddle, The Hey0 Hey1 Hey2 Hey3 Hey4 Hey5
```

because the shell doesn’t understand **`$10`**, **`$11`**, etc. 
It treats `$10` as if it were `${1}0`. 
But it does understand `${10}`, `${11}`, etc., as mentioned in the man page
(“a positional parameter with more than one digit”).

> But don’t actually write scripts like that;
>   there are better ways to deal with long argument lists.

The above (along with many more forms
of `${parameter…something_else}` constructs)
are discussed at greater length in the shell’s man page, [bash(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash).

**A Note on Quotes**

Note that you should always quote shell variables
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing. 
By contrast, while braces can be important,
they’re not as important as quotes.

```
$ filename="nursery rhyme.txt"
$ ls -ld ${filename}
ls: cannot access nursery: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access rhyme.txt: No such file or directory
$ ls -ld "$filename"
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Noob Noob   5309 Jul  2 11:09 nursery rhyme.txt
```

That also applies to positional parameters
(i.e., command-line arguments; e.g., `"$1"`) and also command substitution:

```
$ ls -ld $(date "+%B %Y").txt
ls: cannot access July: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 2015.txt: No such file or directory
$ ls -ld "$(date "+%B %Y").txt"
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Noob Noob    687 Jul  2 11:09 July 2015.txt
```

See [Bash quotes unescaped on command substitution](https://superuser.com/q/909764/354511)
for a brief treatise on the interaction between quotes and `$(`…`)`.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful example. Can you elaborate the use of ! in your example. I don't really understand how does it work.

Comment: @Noob: OK, I elaborated on the use of `!`.

Comment: thanks. Somehow !animal is actually referring to the variable cat instead of the value cat.   Can you also let me know how does /at become a "c" in echo ${animal/at/ow} 
The man explanation of bash is somehow... i don't know. hard to understand.

Comment: also, can you elaborate this phrase - "${parameter} The  value of parameter is substituted."   substituted with what ?  if parameter is fruit and its value is apple - fruit=apple, so ${fruit} - apple is substituted with ?? don't really get the meaning substituted here

Comment: @Noob: “`${!animal}` is actually referring to the variable `$cat` instead of the value cat.”  Yes, that’s exactly the point.  “how does /at become a "c" in echo ${animal/at/ow}?”  Huh?  /at doesn’t become "c"; “cat” becomes “cow” when “at” is replaced with “ow”.

Comment: @Noob: “Also, can you elaborate this phrase: "${parameter} — The value of parameter is substituted."?”  You already understand it.  When you say `echo ${name}`, `foo` is substituted for `${name}`, so it’s as if you had typed `echo foo`.  As a slightly more realistic/practical example, `nursery rhyme.txt` is substituted for `$filename`, so `ls -ld "$filename"` is equivalent to `ls -ld "nursery rhyme.txt"`.

Comment: `$ echo ${!animal}` => `$ echo ${!animal=cat}` 
![](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7291672/209474561-70a25987-d5aa-45d4-8724-1d9eee85d289.png)

Comment: @xgqfrms: It looks like maybe you aren’t running bash. How did you get to that terminal? What does `echo "$SHELL"` say? What does it say if you type a non-existent command (e.g., `xyz`)?

Answer (score 9):

In your example, $var and ${var} are identical. However, curly braces are useful when you wish to expand the variable in a string:

```
    $ string=foo
    $ echo ${string}bar
      foobar
    $ echo $stringbar

    $
```

Thus the curly braces provide a means of substituting the variable in order to get the name of new variable, itself to be substituted.

Answer (score 5):

I usually see it more commonly in strings. Something like this will not work:

```
var="a"
echo "$varRAW_STRING"
```

But this will:

```
var="a"
echo "${var}RAW_STRING"
```

As you correctly said, `$()` is used to execute a command:

```
dir_contents=$(ls)
```

You can also use backticks, but I find the `$()` more versatile. For one thing, backticks cannot be (easily) nested.

```
date_directory=`ls `date '+%Y-%m-%d'`` # Makes no sense
date_directory=$(ls $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')) # Much better
```

Comment: Actually, backticks *can* be nested: `date_directory=\`ls \\`date '+%Y-%m-%d'\\`\``.  But it’s terribly ugly; `$(…)` is much clearer and easier to use.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. It is technically possible, but I cannot imagine anyone ever doing it just because of the readability

Comment: Well, `\`…\`` was ***the*** (only) syntax for command substitution for years before `$(…)` was invented, so you don't need to imagine anything — people did it.

Comment: s/ever doing it/doing it anymore/